# How to properly install Python packages?

Tags: software-installation, python, slackware

I run a Slackware system and I'm trying to run some Python code, but getting a lot of errors such as this one below:

```
>>> import urllib2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/urllib2.py", line 91, in <module>
    import hashlib
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/hashlib.py", line 136, in <module>
    md5 = __get_builtin_constructor('md5')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/hashlib.py", line 63, in __get_builtin_constructor
    import _md5
ImportError: No module named _md5
```

urllib2 should be a rather basic lib with Python, how can I get Python working correctly?

Reason being is that `urllib2` seems to be a dependancy of `praw`: https://github.com/praw-dev/praw/issues/135

Trying to install pip to get this installed gives me:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 5, in <module>
    from setuptools import setup
ImportError: No module named setuptools
```

So I tried installing setuptools:

```
running install
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 94, in <module>
    scripts = scripts,
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/distutils/core.py", line 152, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/distutils/dist.py", line 975, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/distutils/dist.py", line 995, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "/root/setuptools-0.6c11/setuptools/command/install.py", line 76, in run
    self.do_egg_install()
  File "/root/setuptools-0.6c11/setuptools/command/install.py", line 85, in do_egg_install
    easy_install = self.distribution.get_command_class('easy_install')
  File "/root/setuptools-0.6c11/setuptools/dist.py", line 395, in get_command_class
    self.cmdclass[command] = cmdclass = ep.load()
  File "/root/setuptools-0.6c11/pkg_resources.py", line 1954, in load
    entry = __import__(self.module_name, globals(),globals(), ['__name__'])
  File "/root/setuptools-0.6c11/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 21, in <module>
    from setuptools.package_index import PackageIndex, parse_bdist_wininst
  File "/root/setuptools-0.6c11/setuptools/package_index.py", line 2, in <module>
    import sys, os.path, re, urlparse, urllib2, shutil, random, socket, cStringIO
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/urllib2.py", line 91, in <module>
    import hashlib
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/hashlib.py", line 136, in <module>
    md5 = __get_builtin_constructor('md5')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/hashlib.py", line 63, in __get_builtin_constructor
    import _md5
ImportError: No module named _md5
```

Comment: did you try to install pip from http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip, do you have easy_install in your system. try downloading setuptools as tar.gz and then try installing it.

Comment: @harish.venkat Yes, that's what I did; see the bottom part of my question where it fails due to `_md5`

Comment: "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10306531/python-importerror-no-module-named-md5"   "http://johnsofteng.wordpress.com/2009/06/21/python-importerror-no-module-named-_md5/" see this whether this helps

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `pip` or `easy_install` to install python modules.

```
 $ pip install <package-name>
```

**Edit:**

I tried installing `urllib2` package and it told me that the `real name of requirement urllib2 is urllib3`. Here is the what it happened:

```
pradeep@pradeep-laptop:~$ sudo pip install urllib2
Downloading/unpacking urllib2
  Real name of requirement urllib2 is urllib3
  Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement urllib2
No distributions at all found for urllib2
Storing complete log in /home/pradeep/.pip/pip.log
pradeep@pradeep-laptop:~$ sudo pip install urllib3
Downloading/unpacking urllib3
  Downloading urllib3-1.5.tar.gz
  Running setup.py egg_info for package urllib3

Installing collected packages: urllib3
  Running setup.py install for urllib3

Successfully installed urllib3
Cleaning up...
pradeep@pradeep-laptop:~$ python
Python 2.7.3 (default, Apr 20 2012, 22:39:59) 
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import urllib3
>>>
```

**Edit2:**

You can install python-pip from source.

```
$ wget http://pypi.python.org/packages/source/p/pip/pip-0.7.2.tar.gz
$ tar xzf pip-0.7.2.tar.gz
$ cd pip-0.7.2
$ python setup.py install
```

Comment: I get `command not found` on either of those.

Comment: @Zeno: Hey you dont have pip installed in your Slackware. I think you can try `sudo installpkg python-pip`

Comment: I tried that and got `sudo installpkg python-pip  
Cannot install python-pip: package does not end in .tgz`

Comment: @Zeno: I think you can install from tarball using the instructions given in this link: http://guide.python-distribute.org/pip.html#installing-from-other-sources

Comment: Okay, tried that and it's giving me `ImportError: No module named setuptools... so I tried installing setuptools and got `ImportError: No module named _md5` See my edited question for full details

Comment: @Zeno: Really sorry for the above link. Can you try the `Edit2` where i have given the steps how to install python-pip from tarball.

Comment: Yep that's what I tried, from the tgz. The manual install gave me the error `ImportError: No module named setuptools` (see my edited question)

Comment: I dont know what package manager slackware use. But there should be a way to install `pip` using package manager also.

Comment: Slackware doesn't have a built in package manager.

Answer (score 1):

Pip is the right way to go in order to install your Python modules. Easy_installer is the default python package installer, but pip replaces it, and should normally be preferred, though a few packages will only install with easy_installer.

Where other answers are breaking down, here, is how to install software on a slackware machine. Rather than building new software yourself, you should check out Slackbuilds.org. This repository shares a link to the software source, and a custom build script for Slackware to compile the software and make a Slackware package that can easily be installed/uninstalled/upgraded, and is tracked by Slackware's package management system, installpkg/updatepkg/removepkg. Slackbuilds will also let you know of dependencies on other slackbuilds packages. Please note, slackbuilds assumes a comprehensive Slackware installation, and doesn't tell you any dependencies on the standard slack packages.

Assuming Slack 14.0, you will need:
http://slackbuilds.org/repository/14.0/python/pip/
http://slackbuilds.org/repository/14.0/python/distribute/

Finally, please look into slackpkg and sbopkg for more comprehensive automated package management for Slackware. Slackware officially doesn't support slackpkg, or slackbuilds, though they are widely used and well maintained.